# ¿Cómo obtener los valores de una funcion callback?

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, restful

Conecté `nodejs` con `mysql` usando `npm install mysql` y estoy ejecutando una consulta para saber si el usuario está o no en la base de datos. El código que utilizo es el siguiente:

Archivo uno, incluye el servicio y llama la función `consultarLogin`

```
var conexionBD = require('../services/servicioConexionBD');
var **consultarLogin** = conexionBD.consultarLogin(usuarioDescifrado); //mysql@2.12.0
```

Archivo dos ejecuta la función.

```
exports.**consultarLogin** = function (usuarioDecifrado){
console.log(usuarioDecifrado.user);
var existe;
var query =connection.query("select keyusu from datusu where logusu=? and passusu=password(?)",[usuarioDecifrado.user,usuarioDecifrado.pass],function(error,result){
    if(error){
        throw error;
        connection.end();
        console.log(error);
        return error;
    }
    else{
        if(result.length > 0){
            console.log(result[0].keyusu);
            existe= true;
         }
        else
        {
            console.log('Registro no encontrado');
            existe= false;
        }
    }
});

return existe; // siempre queda como indefinido
}
```

Si la consulta devuelve registros la función `consultarLogin` debe retornar un `true`, el problema está en que **el valor de la variable queda en indefinido** aunque yo lo defina como `true` o `false` dentro de la función `callback` del query.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me devuelva `true` o `false` dependiendo del resultado de la consulta y ese sea el resultado que quede almacenado en la variable del archivo uno `consultarLogin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error:

> `connection.query` esta realizando una llamada asincrónica, por lo que `existe` será `undefined` hasta que dicha acción se resuelva.

En otras palabras, el valor `existe` será modificado en algún momento en el tiempo y es por esto que no puedes hacer `return existe;` y esperar que sea `true o false` inmediatamente después de llamar a `connection.query`.

//Solución:

Al llamar a `consultarLogin`, además de pasar el `usuarioDecifrado`, podrías pasar una función `callback` para que al momento de obtener el resultado (`existe=true o false`) llamarla pasando este valor.

Por ejemplo:

```
exports.consultarLogin = function (usuarioDecifrado, callback){
  console.log(usuarioDecifrado.user);
  var query = connection.query("select keyusu from datusu where logusu=? and passusu=password(?)",[usuarioDecifrado.user,usuarioDecifrado.pass],function(error,result){
    if(error){
        throw error;
        connection.end();
        console.log(error);
        return error;
    }
    else{
        if(result.length > 0){
            console.log(result[0].keyusu);
            callback(true);
         }
        else
        {
            console.log('Registro no encontrado');
            callback(false);
        }
    }
  });
}
```

Ejemplo de uso

```
var conexionBD = require('../services/servicioConexionBD');
conexionBD.consultarLogin(usuarioDescifrado, function(existe) {
  var consultarLogin = existe;
  // Aquí todo el código que depende si existe o no
});
```

Comment: Otra opción podría ser, hacer `return query;`, pero como no se que lib estas usando no sé que es `query` y que métodos tiene.

Comment: Completé un poco la pregunta porque aún pasando como parametro una función `callback` no logro que el valor `true` o `false` sea almacenado en la variable del archivo que llama el método, la libreria la instalé así npm install mysql y es la versión mysql@2.12.0.

Comment: Lo solucioné dejando el primer archivo así
   `var consultarLogin = conexionBD.consultarLogin(usuarioDescifrado,function(exito){
        res.status(200).jsonp(consultarLogin);
    });` 
y el segundo tal como lo sugeriste, gracias