# ¿Como leo un archivo .txt en javascript linea por linea?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Buenas, tengo un archivo de texto con varias posibles contraseñas guardado de esta forma:

> 0
> 00
> 000
> 1
> 11
> 111
> 123

Hay muchas más pero es para enseñar por donde van los tiros. No sé como hacer para leerlo línea por línea e ir comparandolo con la contraseña que va poniendo el usuario. El código que tengo es este (para leer el archivo, sacado de otro hilo de Stack Overflow):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#pass").on("change", function() {
    $('#posta').val("Jijiji");
    var path = "../DATUAK/toppasswords.txt";

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='page-wrap'>
  <span><a href='../HTML5/layout.html'>Atzera</a></span> <br><br>

  <h2>Quiz: crazy questions</h2>

  <div>
    <form id="galderenF" name="galderenF" method="post" action="signUp.php" onsubmit="return balidatu()">

      <label for="posta"><strong>Posta (*):</strong></label>
      <input type="email" name="posta" id="posta" placeholder="Zure posta" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2,}[0-9]{3}@ikasle\.ehu\.(eus|es)" required/><br>

      <label for="deitura"><strong>Deitura (*):</strong></label>
      <input type="text" name="deitura" minlength="10" id="galdera" placeholder="Zure deitura" required/><br>

      <label for="nick"><strong>Nick (*):</strong></label>
      <input type="text" name="nick" id="erantzunZuzena" placeholder="Zure nick-a" required/><br>

      <label for="pasahitza"><strong>Pasahitza (*):</strong></label>
      <input type="password" name="pasahitza" minlength="6" id="pass" placeholder="Pasahitza" required/><br>

      <label for="pasEr"><strong>Pasahitza Errepikatu (*):</strong></label>
      <input type="password" name="pasahitzaRep" minlength="6" id="passC" placeholder="Pasahitza errepikatu" required/><br>

      <input class="botoia" type="submit" id="botoia1" value="Erregistratu" />
      <input class="botoia" type="reset" id="botoia2" value="Reset" />
      <div id="aster"><strong> * | Nahitaezko hutsuneak </strong></div><br><br>

    </form>
    <div id="ezkutatu1" style='display:block'>Posta egiaztatzen... </div>
    <div id="erakutsiEgiaBada1" style='display:none'> Posta onargarria da </div>
    <div id="erakutsiGezurraBada2" style='display:none'> Posta existitzen da WSan </div>

    <div id="ezkutatu2" style='display:block'> Pasahitza egiaztatzen... </div>
    <div id="erakutsiEgiaBada2" style='display:none'> Pasahitza onargarria da </div>
    <div id="erakutsiGezurraBada2" style='display:none'> Pasahitza ez da onargarria da </div>
  </div>
```

El problema es que así no consigo leerlo línea por línea, que es lo que quiero para ir comparandolo con la contraseña línea por línea.

Lo necesito en javascript o en jQuery, pero en PHP sería así:

```
    $pasahitzak = fopen('../DATUAK/toppasswords.txt','r');
    while($linea = fgets($pasahitzak) && $ondo==TRUE){
        echo $linea.'<br/>';
    }
    fclose($pasahitzak);
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente, lo que podrías hacer es separar el string por salto de línea (`\n`) y recorrer la lista resultante:

```js
var input = myForm.myInput;
var reader = new FileReader;

input.addEventListener('change', onChange);


function onChange(event) {
  var file = event.target.files[0];
  
  reader.readAsText(file);
  
  reader.onload = onLoad;
  
}

function onLoad() {
  var result = reader.result; // Obtienes el texto
  // En tu ejemplo lo obtienes de una petición HTTP
  
  var lineas = result.split('\n');
  
  
  // o lineas.forEach(function(linea){ ... })
  // o lineas.find(function(linea){ return linea == contraseña })
  for(var linea of lineas) {
    console.log('[linea]', linea)
    //if(linea === passwordBuscar) {
      // Encontraste contraseña
    //}
  }
  
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <input name="myInput" type="file">
</form>
```

**EDICIÓN**

No veo en tú código dónde obtienes el texto de la petición HTTP, puedes hacerlo utilizando el callback [success](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) o como devuelve una Promesa, puedes utilizar el método `then`:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data); // Obtienes el texto
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Lo que no sé es como se importaría el archivo .txt usando una ruta del archivo que sería la siguiente: "../DATUAK/toppasswords.txt"

Comment: He editado mi respuesta. Es eso lo que te faltaba? Estás sirviendo ese archivo como fichero estático?

Comment: No del todo, creo que no se entiende lo que pregunto. Lo que quiero es coger un archivo que tengo en el ordenador en el path que te he puesto en mi anterior comentario. Al coger este archivo leerlo linea por linea y compararlo

Comment: Vale, ahí está el problema. Al ser un archivo de tu Sistema de ficheros (File System) algunos navegadores no te van a dejar "inspeccionar" por tu Sistema de ficheros por razones de seguridad. He hecho alguna prueba y a no ser que haya hecho algo mal, no me deja usar paths relativos, ni siquiera utilizar el path absoluto del fichero, si el fichero está fuera de la carpeta donde está contenido tu HTML. Una solución sería servir el archivo de forma estático desde tu servidor.

Comment: Vale gracias, eso haré entonces

Comment: he utilizado tu código pero he intentado de todas las maneras que se me han ocurrido usar la vble lineas fuera de la funcion onLoad() y no lo he conseguido. ¿Por qué ocurre esto? ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Hola @Nicolas VZ, básicamente por esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39188/cómo-obtener-los-valores-de-una-funcion-callback